# Does a b-tree index speed up min/max queries?

Tags: sql, indexing

Does a b-tree index speed up min/max queries? Could not find information about it. I highly suspect that they do but I need it to be assured.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to completely unsorted, yes, a b-tree will speed up min/max queries. The expected time for finding the min or max for a balanced tree is O(log n).